# Can't get logged into Google Cloud with the PHP client library

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I have followed the steps explained here:
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/#gcloud.init

I ran the script from the CLI and it works fine.

However when I access the .PHP file from my browser and it's run by Apache (www-data user) it says it's not logged in.

How am I supposed to set up the credentials so this also works from a browser?

I tried changing the following line:

```
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
```

by the following:

```
$client->setAuthConfigFile('/var/www/.config/gcloud/credentials');
```

But it doesn't work.

And the following doesn't work either:

```
$client->setAuthConfigFile('/var/www/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json');
```